# Maximum size for a single Wordlist-UIMA RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta

What is the maximum size for a wordlist in Uima Ruta? Because I want to store list of countries, states and cities name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no maximum size for the wordlists in UIMA Ruta. The lines of the file are normally transferred into a char-based in-memory tree structure (TRIE). This means that the size is only restricted by the available RAM and it's memory consumption is less than linear.

My largest wordlist consisted of about 500k entries, as far as I remember. So a list of country names should not be a problem.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*